# Apache Redirection from HTTPS to HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: apache-httpd

I'm having a strange behavior on Apache 2.4

When I do GET on:

```
https://www.example.com/signup
```

it goes

```
https://www.example.com/signup -301-> **http**://www.example.com/signup/ -301-> https://www.example.com/signup/ -200-> https://www.example.com/signup/
```

I'm not sure why it redirects the HTTPS to HTTP and then back to HTTPS.

The Virtualhost looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 Servername www.${APACHE_HOSTNAME}
 ServerAlias ${APACHE_HOSTNAME}
 <If "req('Host') == '${APACHE_HOSTNAME}'">
    Redirect permanent / https://www.${APACHE_HOSTNAME}/
 </If>
Alias "/signup" "/var/www/html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ServerPath /signup/
```

solved this.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 Servername www.${APACHE_HOSTNAME}
 ServerAlias ${APACHE_HOSTNAME}
 ServerPath /signup/
 <If "req('Host') == '${APACHE_HOSTNAME}'">
    Redirect permanent / https://www.${APACHE_HOSTNAME}/
 </If>
</VirtualHost>
```